# Joined member avatar displayed in thumbnail of embed - Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I've created a message embed that get's sent to a channel whenever a member joins the server. I used the following code for this.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {

let welcomeRole = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'ROLE');

guildMember.roles.add(welcomeRole);

let welcomeEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

    .setColor('#202225')
    .setTitle('New member spotted!')
    .setDescription(`Welcome ${guildMember}!`)
    .setThumbnail(guildMember.displayAvatarURL())


guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID').send(welcomeEmbed);
```

So the user's avatar doesn't show, although a normal image does of course. I'm suspecting it's because I'm not using the `user` class, could be something else, I have no idea.

My question is then, how can I display the joined user's avatar in the embed's thumbnail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend doing:

```js
.setThumbnail(guildMember.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
```

This will show the users avatar and if it's animated, it will be displayed animated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the avatar of a GuildMember object, but would first have to convert it into a User object.

This can be simply done using:

```
.setThumbnail(guildMember.user.displayAvatarURL())
```